# iptables: Can't specify dport

Tags: yocto, iptables

I'm trying to add iptables rule on a specific port.

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT`

fails: "unknown option: --dport"

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT`

fails: "Couldn't load match 'tcp': No such file or directory"

Initially I thought that the tcp extension is missing, but when running "strace",
it look that iptables loads the file "/usr/lib/xtables/libxt_tcp.so".

I'm building custom image, using yocto, at dunfell release.
What am I missing?

Comment: Were you able to resolve/work past this? I am on dunfell/3.1.3 and am having the same issue.

Comment: I was able to make this work by setting CONFIG_NETFILTER_XTABLES to Y instead of M in my kernel config. However, I don't understand why this works because I had inserted the relevant modules (as far as I could tell) so modular versus built in should yield the same behavior.